# Difference between 4 controls with 0dip width and weight=1, and the same conditions with weight = 0.25

Tags: android, layout

Consider 4 `TextView`s inside a `horizontal layout` each of which has `Layout width` of 0 and `Layout weight` of 1. What is the difference when they all have `Layout width` of 0.25 instead? It seems the output is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it is fairly simple to understand.

`layout_width=0dp` and `layout_weight=1` means that you want all the views to take equal space horizontally.

whereas

`layout_width=0dp` and `layout_weight=0.25` means that you want all the views to take 1/4 times the space of the total width of the parent.

This value becomes equal in case you have 4 views to be placed and not always.

Answer (score 0):

`Linear layout` says, give every `textview` a(0.25 weight) `25%` space (considering `100`% available space). since there are 4 `textview` , so 100`%` would be divided among 4 as `25%` ratio. Now linear layout gives each `textview 25%` space, textview weight `1` i.e `100`% says, fill all the available space that is given to you by `linear layout`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

The spacing (`layout_width`) is calculated as a percentage of the total. In other words, if each `TextView` has a `layout_weight` of 1 then the total is 4 but each `TextView`  gets 1 out of 4 (i.e., a quarter).

When using 0.25 the total is 1 but 0.25 is a quarter of 1 so, again, each `TextView` gets a quarter of the space.